# Are all referenced libraries loaded at startup

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, dll, runtime

I'm writing some code which depends on certain libraries being loaded before I ever reference them in code. I know I can load them manually but I'm trying to avoid that.

In my test cases, it looks like any assembly referenced by my silverlight app is present in `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` even before I make use of anything in it.

I was under the impression that assemblies are loaded only as needed, is this not the case?

---

In anticipation of assemblies being loaded only when needed, and my only need being reflection, I have the following in the project that needs to be loaded:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)]
public class LoadFirst : Attribute {}
```

with

```
[assembly: LoadFirst]
```

Will that work to force load? It looks like it's what log4net has done with `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bernard,

When you create an assembly by **referencing** other assemblies, (early binding). All reference details are recorded within the metadata of the newly create assembly and the CLR will check and load the referenced assemblies when you try to load your assembly. If CLR fails to load any of the referenced assemblies (or other assemblies referenced by the referenced assemblies) the load process will fail.

Then there is the late binding where you would use reflection which happens at the runtime.

In both of the cases, the referenced assembly would be loaded, but instances of types defined within will not be created in the managed heap until your code would do so expletively. For example, let’s say there is an assembly called **MyCryptoLib.dll** which defines a type called **OSCryptoLib** to describe encryption libraries offered by the OS. And it also exposes a method called **GetOSCryptoLib** to get a list of OSCryptoLib.

When you reference **MyCryptoLib.dll** in your assembly and load your assembly, CLR will locate and load **MyCryptoLib** (and any other assemblies required by MyCryptoLib) but would not create any instances of **OSCryptoLib** without your code first calling method **GetOSCryptoLib**

In SilverLight have a look at **AssemblyPart**, and see whether that would help in any way

Hope this helps